# How to use Statsmodels and Seaborn in anaconda

Tags: anaconda, seaborn, statsmodels

I installed the latest version of Anaconda with all available packages. I want to use Statsmodels and Seaborn and some other installed environments. I am new to this, and still couldn't figure it out how. I see they are installed there. but I don't know how to start & use them. Can you guide me how to start these environments. I was only able to use Orange which is easily available on the navigator menu. Thanks.

Here is a snapshot of my anaconda navigator:

[image]

Here is a snapshot of anaconda environments:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a Notebook, start IPython, or start Spyder. Then type

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import seaborn as sns
```

and you are ready to go with whatever you want to do with those modules.

Comment: I am sorry, but do they require programming or graphical interface?

Comment: statsmodels as well as seaborn are python packages. So they are meant to be used with python programming language.

Comment: I see. So I can't use them. I was mistaken.

Comment: if it's not too much, can you suggest  similar software with graphical interface and possibly open source? thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what Software would be similar but with GUI. (Other than maybe LibreOffice Calc?) You may inquire at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (but make sure to clearly state your requirements when posting there).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.